# How can I dynamically draw images on a windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, graphics

I am in the process of converting a snake game I previously wrote in Python to C#. I am very new to C# and Visual Studio, so I am not sure what the best practice is to dynamically draw images to the screen.

There are two lists, `xPositions` and `yPositions`, which hold the x and y coordinates of each square of the snake. I wish to draw `snakeIMG`, which represents a single square of the snake, at each point in `xPositions` and `yPositions`. Each time the method to draw the snake is called, the snake should be erased and redrawn in its updated position.

The pictureBox, `background`, holds an image of the board that I wish to draw the snake on top of.

I attempted to do this with the following function:

```
// draw the snake in its current position
public void drawSnake()
{
        PictureBox[] snake = new PictureBox[this.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        {
                snake[i] = new PictureBox();
                snake[i].Parent = background;
                snake[i].Image = snakeIMG;
                snake[i].Location = new Point(this.xPositions[i], this.yPositions[i]);
                snake[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                snake[i].BringToFront();
         }
}
```

The above code fails to achieve the goal.

Using multiple picture boxes to hold each part of the snake does not seem to be an efficient solution since the images are dynamic.

How should I draw the images to the form so that each time I call the function `drawSnake()` the previous snake is erased and the snake is drawn in its new position?

Comment: There's some good documentation on using the Paint event and the Graphics object associated with the event [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: [Graphics.DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)